# Keep advanced option (kernel version) after reboot

Tags: upgrade, kernel, updates, 22.04

TLDR: 5.19.0-50-generic is working but I have to select it from advanced ubuntu options on each restart. (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, after NVIDIA driver install when no space on disk)

Complete story:
My disk was full. I didn't know. I restarted the computer and the resolution was very bad. I tried to install NVIDIA driver when I received the message that the disk is full. Somehow, before deleting files to have space, the installer told me to restart to apply changes.

When I restarted I received a black screen. Ctrl + Alt + F1, etc didn't work. So, all I had was a black screen on each restart. Recovery mode didn't work - just saying forever Loading...

I solved the disk space problem using a bootable USB with Ubuntu live. Now I have 20 GB free. It did not solve the black screen.

I tried the recovery mode again. I had the menu by pressing Shift on start. The first option: linux-image-6.2.0-1010-gcp is starting now, but the resolution is bad, also the internet is not working. I tried to install drivers downloading them on other computer. Not working.

But I found 5.19.0-50-generic is working in my case. It seems everything is good if I select this option in that menu. (I don't select the recovery mode, but the normal mode.)

I not good with this type of work, but somehow I have my PC working again. This is what I have now:

```
$ uname -r
5.19.0-50-generic
```

Also this is the list of possible versions I think:

```
$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-34-generic                          5.11.0-34.36                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-36-generic                          5.11.0-36.40                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic                          5.11.0-38.42                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-20-generic                          5.13.0-20.20                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic                          5.13.0-21.21                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-22-generic                          5.13.0-22.22                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-23-generic                          5.13.0-23.23                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic                          5.13.0-25.26                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic                          5.13.0-27.29                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-28-generic                          5.13.0-28.31                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic                          5.13.0-30.33                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-35-generic                          5.13.0-35.40                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-37-generic                          5.13.0-37.42                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic                          5.13.0-39.44                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic                          5.13.0-40.45                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-1029-nvidia                         5.15.0-1029.29                             amd64        Signed kernel image nvidia
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-1036-intel-iotg                     5.15.0-1036.41                             amd64        Signed kernel image intel-iotg
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-1038-gcp                            5.15.0-1038.46                             amd64        Signed kernel image gcp
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-1039-oracle                         5.15.0-1039.45                             amd64        Signed kernel image oracle
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-1040-aws                            5.15.0-1040.45                             amd64        Signed kernel image aws
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-1042-azure                          5.15.0-1042.49                             amd64        Signed kernel image azure
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-27-generic                          5.15.0-27.28                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-30-generic                          5.15.0-30.31                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-33-generic                          5.15.0-33.34                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-37-generic                          5.15.0-37.39                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-39-generic                          5.15.0-39.42                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-40-generic                          5.15.0-40.43                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-41-generic                          5.15.0-41.44                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic                          5.15.0-43.46                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic                          5.15.0-46.49                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic                          5.15.0-47.51                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic                          5.15.0-48.54                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic                          5.15.0-50.56                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-52-generic                          5.15.0-52.58                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-53-generic                          5.15.0-53.59                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic                          5.15.0-56.62                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-57-generic                          5.15.0-57.63                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-58-generic                          5.15.0-58.64                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-60-generic                          5.15.0-60.66                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-67-generic                          5.15.0-67.74                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-69-generic                          5.15.0-69.76                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-70-generic                          5.15.0-70.77                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-71-generic                          5.15.0-71.78                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-72-generic                          5.15.0-72.79                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic                          5.15.0-73.80                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-75-generic                          5.15.0-75.82                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-76-generic                          5.15.0-76.83                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-78-generic                          5.15.0-78.85                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-78-lowlatency                       5.15.0-78.85                               amd64        Signed kernel image lowlatency
rc  linux-image-5.17.0-1035-oem                            5.17.0-1035.36                             amd64        Signed kernel image oem
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency              5.19.0-1010.10                             amd64        Signed kernel image nvidia-lowlatency
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-1014-nvidia                         5.19.0-1014.14                             amd64        Signed kernel image nvidia
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-1014-nvidia-lowlatency              5.19.0-1014.14                             amd64        Signed kernel image nvidia-lowlatency
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-1027-gcp                            5.19.0-1027.29~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image gcp
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-1027-oracle                         5.19.0-1027.30                             amd64        Signed kernel image oracle
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-1029-aws                            5.19.0-1029.30~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image aws
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-1030-lowlatency                     5.19.0-1030.30                             amd64        Signed kernel image lowlatency
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-32-generic                          5.19.0-32.33~22.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic                          5.19.0-35.36~22.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic                          5.19.0-38.39~22.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic                          5.19.0-40.41~22.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-41-generic                          5.19.0-41.42~22.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-42-generic                          5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-43-generic                          5.19.0-43.44~22.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-45-generic                          5.19.0-45.46~22.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic                          5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.19.0-50-generic                          5.19.0-50.50                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-25-generic                           5.8.0-25.26                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-28-generic                           5.8.0-28.30                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-31-generic                           5.8.0-31.33                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-33-generic                           5.8.0-33.36                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic                           5.8.0-34.37                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-36-generic                           5.8.0-36.40                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-38-generic                           5.8.0-38.43                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-41-generic                           5.8.0-41.46                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-44-generic                           5.8.0-44.50                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-45-generic                           5.8.0-45.51                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-48-generic                           5.8.0-48.54                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-50-generic                           5.8.0-50.56                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic                           5.8.0-53.60                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-59-generic                           5.8.0-59.66                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-63-generic                           5.8.0-63.71                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.0.0-1020-oem                             6.0.0-1020.20                              amd64        Signed kernel image oem
rc  linux-image-6.1.0-1017-oem                             6.1.0-1017.17                              amd64        Signed kernel image oem
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-1003-nvidia                          6.2.0-1003.3~22.04.1+1                     amd64        Signed kernel image nvidia
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-1008-aws                             6.2.0-1008.8~22.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image aws
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-1008-azure                           6.2.0-1008.8~22.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image azure
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-1009-lowlatency                      6.2.0-1009.9~22.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image lowlatency
ii  linux-image-6.2.0-1010-gcp                             6.2.0-1010.10~22.04.1                      amd64        Signed kernel image gcp
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic                           6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                                    5.15.0.78.75                               amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04                          5.19.0.50.22                               amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

The question is how can I make sure, the computer will work after restart without new configuration? Also how can I make sure my Ubuntu is updated? (I already run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt autoremove`)

Also if you can explain what that menu really means? (the menu with options for advanced starting). Thank you very much.

Comment: "*Also how can I make sure my Ubuntu is updated?*" Just read your apt output.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using this tool:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

`$ grub-customizer`

Set 5.19.0-50-generic as predefined. But also set to use saved one (last used kernel). Now it starts each time with a working kernel version.