# My eth0 and wlan0 disappeared and i have no internet...how do i fix

Tags: internet, cinnamon

I messed up big time.

It started when I opened my computer and got an error saying cinnamon crashed going into fallback mode.
When this happened it showed that my internet was connected however 2hen I tried using apps that required internet it said I had no internet.

I looked up how to solve the issue and ended up deleting cinnamon but also rebooted my computer by mistake.

Now when I try to log in I get an error unable to launch "cinnamon-session-cinnamon" X session---
"cinnamon-session-cinnamon"  not found; falling back

And I get a black screen.

I used ctrl + alt +f1 to get to the command line and have been trying to fix it but it seems it's not plausible without an I telnet connection which I can't seem to get.

Please help me fix this I'm new to linux

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is just a you thing - I had a similar experience this morning and I think it's related to a kernel update.  Rolling back to an older version fixed all my issues.

I had the same experience as described in this post: [Keep advanced option (kernel version) after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1479740/keep-advanced-option-kernel-version-after-reboot)

Comment: When I tried this I got an error saying unable to initiate server could not connect connection refused 
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer.

Comment: When I tried this